# Show that $\det(A) = 0$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

> If $A$ is a $5\times 5$ matrix such that $A^T = - A$, show that $\det(A) = 0$.

I have solved it but I have trouble understanding the significance of the $5\times 5$ in the question.

Comment: Consider $B= \pmatrix{0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0}$. Now $B^t  =B$; does your proof show that $\det B = 0$?

Comment: It is true for all odd exponents (see the solution of @Math Lover)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: For an $n \times n$ matrix $A$, $\det(A^T) = \det(A)$ and $\det(-A)=(-1)^n \det(A)$.

Answer (score 0):

$det(A)=det(A^t)=det(-A)=(-1)^5det(A)=-det(A)$ this implies that $det(A)=0$.

Answer (score 0):

$$A^t=-A$$
$$\det(A^t)=\det(-A)$$
$$\det(A)=(-1)^n\det(A)$$
$$\det(A)(1-(-1)^n)=0$$

Since $n=5 \implies (-1)^n=-1$

$$2\det(A)=0$$
Therefore
$$\det(A)=0$$